# Method signature in Swift

Tags: swift, function

By default I had expected, that in Swift the method signature includes the method name and it parameter types. But then I faced with protocol UITableViewDataSource containing:

```
optional public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? 

optional public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String?
```

The external parameter name (titleForHeaderInSection vs titleForFooterInSection) is the only difference in this methods.

So am I right, that external parameter also defines the method signature, or I have missed something? [Function section](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html) in swift documentation does not help me with that.